# How to update the current date, time in format dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss in an oracle table through python

Tags: python, sql, oracle, sql-update, cx-oracle

I am trying to update a date type column in an Oracle table but I am getting below error:

```
sql2 = f"""update a_table SET COMPLETION_DATE = '{datetime.datetime.now()}' WHERE ID=1"""
data2 = cursor.execute(sql2)
```

cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

for information : I am using cx_Oracle module.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set `completion_date` to the current date/time, you can just use `sysdate` in the query:

```
UPDATE a_table SET completion_date = SYSDATE WHERE ID=1
```

This assumes that `completion_date` is of `date` datatype. If that's a `timestamp` instead:

```
UPDATE a_table SET completion_date = SYSTIMESTAMP WHERE ID=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is, that the SQL string produced in the variable `sql2` looks like this

```
update a_table SET COMPLETION_DATE = '2020-12-14 14:09:11.553590' WHERE ID=1
```

The timestamp literal may cause problems in the conversion and you'll have to use expplicite conversion to make it safe (or use database value from `SYSTIMESTAMP`as proposed in other answer).

```
update a_table 
SET COMPLETION_DATE = to_timestamp('2020-12-14 14:09:11.553590','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF6')
WHERE ID=1
```

**Anyway** don't forget that the *usage of bind variables is encouraged*, so your solution should look something like this

```
sql2 =  "update a_table SET COMPLETION_DATE = :TST WHERE ID = :ID"
data2 = cursor.execute(sql2, TST = datetime.datetime.now(), ID = 1 )
```

The big advantage is that you get one SQL statement that may be reused for all `ID`s and timestamps.

If the column data type is `TIMESTAMP` and you want to insert  also the *milliseconds* you have to add the `setinputsizes` before the `execute` statement - otherwise they will be truncated.

```
 cursor.setinputsizes(TST=cx_Oracle.TIMESTAMP)
```